# How to write separate content on one line using html?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web development and am trying to create this page as an exercise.
[original page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRaLu.jpg)
this is my code

```html
<body bgcolor="white" <div width=1030px height=150px style="color: white;background-color:black ">
  <p><i>DUNUKA</i></p>
  <nav align="right">
    <a href=" indexOld.html " style="text-decoration: none;color: white ">PORIFPLIO|</a>
    <a href="about.html " style="text-decoration: none ;color: white ">ABOUT|</a>
    <a href="contact.html " style="text-decoration: none;color: white ">CONTACT|</a>
  </nav>
  <br>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: grey " width=1020px height=100px>
    <br>
    <p align="center "> Protfolio</p>
    <br>
    <hr />
    <br>
  </div>

  <div height=800px width=1 010px>
    <table border="0px " cellspacing="0px " bgcolor="white " width="1000px " height="320px ">
      <tr align="center ">
        <td><img src="p1.png " width="150px " height="130px " /></td>
        <td><img src="p3.png " width="150px " height="130px " /></td>
        <td><img src="p6.png " width="150px " height="130px " /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center ">
        <td><img src="p2.png " width="150px " height="130px " /></td>
        <td><img src="p4.png " width="150px " height="130px " /></td>
        <td><img src="p6.png " width="150px " height="130px " /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div style="color: white;background-color: black " align="center " width=1020px height=200px>
    <br />
    <p>@All rights received</p>
    <img src="google_plus_img.png " height="15px " width="15px " />
    <img src="facebook_img.png " height="15px " width="15px " />
    <img src="twitter_img.png " height="15px " width="15px " />
    <img src="linkedin_img.png " height="15px " width="15px " />
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
</body>
```

This is how the page I created looks like
[my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA6e5.png)

In the original image the text DINUKA and the links PORTFOLIO,ABOUT,CONTACT  appear on the same line(on the same level of the page) but on my page they appear on two lines.How can I make the them appear on the same line?I'm new to web development

Comment: check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp)

Answer (score 1):

1) At the basic level you can use breakline. `<br/>`

2) You can use `align:right` CSS property inside the div.

3) You can easily start to use Bootstrap-3/4 inside your code which will ease lots of your tasks.

Link: https://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

I recomend against writing CSS in HTML (You should make a different CSS sheet and link to it), but here is a quick fix :)

[Check it out here](https://jsfiddle.net/51axy8nb/)

```
<div style="color: white;background-color:black;height: 50px;">
<div id="navBarContent" style="line-height: 40px; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; ">
    <p style="display: inline-block; margin: 0; ">
        <i>DUNUKA</i>
    </p>

    <nav align="right" style="display: inline-block; float: right;">
        <a href="indexOld.html" style="text-decoration: none;color: white">PORIFPLIO|</a>
        <a href="about.html" style="text-decoration: none ;color: white">ABOUT|</a>
        <a href="contact.html" style="text-decoration: none;color: white">CONTACT|</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I would recomend you take a look at Bootstrap when you've become comfortable using CSS, it will make your whole web-design experience a lot easier :) 
[Get Bootstrap Here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/)

Comment: If it helped you please click the 'checkmark' under the upvote / downvote.

Answer (score 0):

In your code change

```
<p><i>DUNUKA</i></p>
<nav align="right">
```

to

```
<span><i>DUNUKA</i></span>
<nav style="display: inline-block; float: right;>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the width of you p tag and nav is 100% you can try to add these styles

for p add

```
width: 100px;
    display: inline;
```

and for nav add

```
width: 300px;
float: right;
```

for the div that is 1030px

```
padding: 8px;
```